# SAS to delete observations that meet condition within group

Tags: if-statement, sas, grouping

I want to delete records in the `Have` dataset which meets all the following conditions. *ID_num* here stands for the 3-digit part of the `ID` field

- ID = Mxxx
- Type = blood
- located prior to any of the following records **WITHIN EACH GROUP OF (*ID_num*, drug)**.

  - ID=Mxxx and Type=milk
  - ID=Infxxx

Below are `Have` and the desired output.

```
data have;
     input ID $ Type $ Drug $;
     cards;
M001    blood A
M001    blood A
M001    blood A
M001    blood B
M001    blood B
M001    milk  B
M001    blood C
M001    blood C
M002    blood A
M002    blood A
Inf002  blood A
M002    blood A
M002    blood B
M002    milk  C
Inf003  blood B
M003    blood B
;
run;
```

```
data want;
     input ID $ Type $ Drug $;
     cards;
M001    milk   B
Inf002  blood  A
M002    blood  A
M002    milk   C
Inf003  blood  B
M003    blood  B
;
run;
```

For example, the M002 (blood, drug A) that is under the inf002 drug A observation stays because it occurs after an infant sample in the same drug group. But two M002 (blood, A) observations above it should get deleted as they occur before the first infant sample in same drug group. Conversely, the two M001 (blood, C) observations following M001 (milk, B) should be deleted as the drug groups are different.

Comment: What to do if a mother blood locates between two mother milks, or between a mother milk and a infant blood, or two infant bloods?

Comment: Your results do not match your description. Why is the first observation not kept?  Did you mean you want to delete all BLOOD records that occur before the **first** MILK record for the Mother?

Comment: @Bill Huang, if the mother blood sample is between any of those two samples and is from the same drug group as the milk or infant blood, it would be kept. Otherwise, if we have a mother blood from drug B, for example, sandwiched between an infant from group A and milk from group C, it'd get deleted. On the other hand, if we have mother blood from A, followed by Infant blood from A, followed by mother blood from A again, the last mother blood would be kept, but the first one gets deleted.

Comment: @Tom, thank you for the correction and sorry for the confusion. Yes, you're absolutely right, what I meant to say is that all mother blood records per drug group that occur BEFORE THE FIRST milk sample or before the first infant sample should be deleted. If a mother blood within a certain drug group occurs after a milk or infant sample from the same drug group, then it should be kept. But if an infant sample in drug group A, for example, and then a mother blood from group B occurs right after it, then this mother blood would not be kept as it is from a different drug group.

Comment: Thank you, Bill. I have edited my post and included the updated want vs have datasets. Hope this is more clear now. I'm sorry for any confusion, I just realized this morning that my post was not very clear and missing important details.

Comment: The following is my current understanding of your logic and data: For each group (001,002,etc, including mothers and infants), (1) There is at most 1 infant record per group (2) Delete everything until a `infant` or a `mother milk` record appears (3) Delete every `mother blood` record except the one immediately after `mother-milk` or `infant`. Is that correct? How does `Drug` work?

Comment: Moreover, what if `mother milk` or `infant` never appears in a group? Should all the records in that group get deleted?

Comment: @Bill, for (1), we can have more than 1 infant record per group; (2) all mother blood before a first infant or mother milk should be deleted; if mother blood appears after milk or infant associated with same drug group as mother blood, then it stays, otherwise delete; (3) All mother blood samples that appear after mother milk or infant samples should stay ONLY IF they're from same drug group as the milk/infant samples.

Comment: @Bill, if mother milk or infant never appears in a drug group, that's fine. That just means that all the mother blood samples for that drug group get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: group by (`gp`, `Drug`).

### Keys

1. Extract the `ID` grouping number (`gp` in the code) using [SAS regex](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p1vz3ljudbd756n19502acxazevk.htm&locale=en) (`prxmatch(patt, var)` here).
2. The keep condition can be examined row-by-row while also grouped by (`gp`, `Drug`). A change in `gp` is identified by `FIRST.drug`.

   - The dataset must be sorted before the use of `BY` statement. Since SAS sorting is stable, the original ordering won't break.
   - The original ordering can be tracked by recording `_n_` in the regex parsing phase.

### Code

```
* "have" is in your post;
data tmp;
    set have;
    pos = prxmatch('(\d{3})', ID);
    gp = substr(ID, pos, pos+2);  * group number;
    mi = substr(ID, 1, 1);  * mother or infant;
    n = _n_; * keep track of the original ordering;
    drop pos;
run;

proc sort data=tmp out=tmp;
    by gp drug;
run;

data want(drop=flag_keep gp mi);
    set tmp;
    by gp drug;
    * state variables;
    retain flag_keep 0;
    if FIRST.drug then flag_keep = 0;
    * mark keep;
    if (flag_keep = 1) or (mi = "I") or ((mi = "M") and (Type = "milk"))
        then flag_keep = 1;
    if flag_keep = 1 then output;
run;

proc sort data=want out=want;
    by n;
run;
```

Result: the original row number `n` is shown for clarity.

```
   ID      Type   Drug  n
1  M001    milk   B     6    
2  Inf002  blood  A     11    
3  M002    blood  A     12    
4  M002    milk   C     14    
5  Inf003  blood  B     15    
6  M003    blood  B     16
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help! This works EXCEPT for the situation when I add more observations into the mix (see edits to my original post). I'm sorry I should have clarified to begin with, but I basically want to delete all mother blood observations WITHIN a drug group that occur before the first sample of milk or infant blood for that same blood group. So, in edited have dataset, the 2 M001 (blood, C) observations should get deleted eventhough they occur after the milk sample (drug B) from same participant because the drugs are different.

Comment: *Meant to say "WITHIN a drug group that occur before the first sample of milk or infant blood for that same *DRUG*, not blood group

Comment: thank you so much for your help with this, I greatly appreciate it! It works perfectly now. I also accepted your proposed edits for making my original post more clear and to the point, thank you!